# Изменения css, проверенные в браузере, не работают в css файле wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

---

Появилась следующая проблема: делая сайт на вордпрессе, проверяю некоторые стили в браузере. При проверке в браузере этот код работает, а при использовании в моей теме, нет.

[image: до]

[image: после]

Это очень простые изменения, вставляя их в css сайта ничего не происходит.
Если есть идеи, буду благодарен.

ПС. пробовал вствлять также в специальный редактор css от wordpress.

ПСС. файл css правильный, все остальные поправки работают как надо.

Comment: если инспектор показывает перечеркнутым, значит, что-то в другом месте их переопределяет. Ищите.

Answer (score 0):

Ему мешают другие стили (возможно стили плагинов), нужно, либо удалить их, либо прописать для конфликтных стилей !important. Так же, рекомендую подключать свой css файл всегда последним, чтобы он имел наибольший приоритет (это третий вариант решения)

Comment: использовать `!important` - дурной тон, всегда нужно стараться искать другое решение проблемы

Answer (score 0):

стили прописаны на самой странице через тег , так как показывает в правом верхнем углу (index):50 на 50 строке в самой странице. Обычно там где сейчас(index)  пишется  пишется название подключенного файла где находятся стили(если файл подключен.
вот как у меня[image: мой вариант подключения стилей темы]

Comment: а если там написано index:50 то где искать

Comment: Наведите на (index):50 должен показать путь к странице http://prntscr.com/opgo3y

Comment: Если нажать на  (index):50  откроется вёрстка страницы, и место где написан нужный стиль